# Cakephp 4 show only logged in user data

Tags: cakephp

I am pretty new in CakePHP, working with CMS tutorial.
In the end, I'd like list all users, if logged in user is 'admin', if not, only the active user in users/index.

At first, I've tried to get logged in user data and search the user in db, but it not works.
My code is:

```
 public function index()
    {

        
        $this->Authorization->skipAuthorization();
        $user=$this->request->getAttribute('identity');
        $user->get('user_id');       
        

        $users = $this->paginate($this->Users->get($user));  

        $this->set(compact('users'));
    }
```

The error is:

```
Record not found in table "users" with primary key [App\Model\Entity\User::__set_state(array(
```

Answer (score 0):

At the point where you're calling `$this->Users->get($user)`, `$user` is the result of `$this->request->getAttribute('identity')`, which is, as the error indicates, a User entity, not an integer. In between, you are calling `$user->get('user_id');`, but you're not doing anything with the result of that call. Either assign the result of this call into a variable that you pass into `$this->Users->get()`, or else just do `$this->Users->get($user->get('user_id'))`.

Of course, passing the result of `->get()` into `->paginate()` makes no sense, but that's presumably the next thing you'll work on.